# How to put jobs inside a folder in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to put jobs inside a folder using jenkins DSL script
Now i create a listView and i put inside my jobs here the code i'm using

```
listView('MyJobsList') {
  jobs {
     map.each{
       name((it.key).trim())
     }
  }
   columns{
        status()
        weather()
        name()
        lastSuccess()
        lastFailure()
        lastDuration()
        buildButton()
    }
}
```

i want to do the same thing but this time i want to put the jobs in a folder !!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please refer the below Job-DSL documentation to create a folder in Jenkins through Job-DSL.

[Folder](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/folder)

```
folder('folder-a') {
    description('Folder containing all jobs for folder-a')
}
job('folder-a/job-a') {
    // Job config goes here
}
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect for modern versions of Jenkins.

Comment: @christopher can you explain what is wrong with it? This answer matches the current job DSL documentation here:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands
"Items can be created within folders by using the full path as job name."

Answer (score -1):

Please, take a look at Jenkins filestructure: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Here you can see where jobs are stored by default (job config and build logs). You can not and should not change this filestructure with DSL script (JobDSL plugin).