# Jenkins job DSL list view does not create a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

The below job DSL creates a new job, list view, and *should* add the new job to the view, but it's not adding the job to the view- the job runs without any errors though:

```
multibranchPipelineJob("myjob") {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        bitbucket {
          credentialsId('bitbucket-login-user-pass')
          repoOwner('myteam')
          repository('myrepo')
          autoRegisterHook(true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//listview is created, but job not added to it
listView('mylistview') {
  jobs {
    name('myjob')
  }
}
```

I suspect I'm doing something dumb. Everything is created but when I click on the tab for the "mylistview", "myjob" is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb now, but this behavior is a little odd. Looks like you need to add columns to the view or you won't see anything!

[How to put jobs inside a folder in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387792/how-to-put-jobs-inside-a-folder-in-jenkins)

```
listView('MyJobsList') {
  jobs {
     map.each{
       name((it.key).trim())
     }
  }
   columns{
        status()
        weather()
        name()
        lastSuccess()
        lastFailure()
        lastDuration()
        buildButton()
    }
}
```